# Mobile phone application design guidelines

Tags: graphics, user-interface, mobile, mobile-phones

Any documents or articles that contain design guidelines for creating mobile phone applications? How applications should be built for ideal user experiences.

- User Interface & Keypad
- Graphics
- Languages

Links from specific manufacturers are also welcome.

Comment: How about guidelines based on personal experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's design guidelines for Windows Mobile applications is fairly okay and makes sense for most mobile applications in general: [Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879586.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

- Help the user avoid laborious text-entry (this applies to all phones *except* my beloved Samsung i760 and all other phones with a full physical keyboard)
- Keep the screens as sparse and simple as possible - avoid the urge to cram as many controls and as much text and graphics onto a form as will fit
- Don't write applications like "Shake the Baby"
- Remember to test your application outside in full sunlight - mobile apps are a lot like vampires
- Avoid device- and manufacturer-specific code whenever possible

Comment: +1 for Avoid device- and manufacturer-specific code whenever possible.
:)

Answer (score 1):

- high contrast (sunlight issue that MusiGenesis mentioned)
- I tend to prefer 100% widths on everything to accommodate for multiple widths
- For larger projects, I'll incorporate WURFL to at least get the device's screen dimensions and adjust necessary pieces like font size and or fixed-width graphics

Answer (score 0):

Some application design wisdom:

- behaviour is consistent or predictable
- feedback is provided
- the user's memory is not strained
- dialogue is task-oriented