# How to design a website for mobile phone users?

Tags: mobile-phones

How can i start the development of a site that can be browse from mobile phones? For example, if i browse my website http://xavytech.com site from a browser it looks fine which is known by everyone... I am extending my website to browse through nokia mobile phones..

- Where should i start?
- How to write   css or should i
  recreate a new website    for mobile
  phones?

Comment: See some related questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596724/tools-for-making-a-site-design-mobile-phone-friendly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415437/mobile-phone-application-design-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

The [Sencha Project](http://www.sencha.com/) here was just announced that offers an HTML5 framework for mobile devices.  It works well with Safari on iOS and the Android web browser.

Try out the examples [here](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/) with a Nokia phone to see if it's something you want.

Comment: Sencha Touch does not support any Nokia phone today - it's exclusively iOS and Android.